# Making static image scrollable

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails app currently hosted at Heroku, where I serve a static image. I've tried various methods / CSS combinations of making the image scrollable and nothing seems to work. Currently I use `background-size:cover` and it works fine for people with larger screen resolution, but the problem is the image is not scrollable for people with smaller screen resolution, i.e. the image gets cut off.

This is what is currently used:

```css
body {
    background-image: url('#file path');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    background-color: #464646;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

(#file path being a link to an Amazon S3 static image)

Any suggestions on how to make this possible ?

Comment: The body won't scroll if there is no width set, you could use contain instead of cover, which would scale the background to fit, but if you want it to horizontal scroll you will need to set a size and set the overflow-x to scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding: `.myClass img {overflow:scroll;}` to your CSS to tell the browser to allow the overflow content to be scrolled to see.

**EDIT:** This can't be accomplished using cover from what I tested, try changing it to a different background-size (ex. `contain`).